# Impact of unnecessary --platform flag for a docker run command

Tags: docker, apple-m1

I'm running MS SQL Server in a Docker container for some local testing. The command I use is:

`docker run --platform linux/amd64 -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=<redacted>' -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest`

The `--platform` parameter is necessary for the container to run at all on my Mac M1 machine. However, if I put this command into a script, or into a fabric8 configuration in Maven, can I safely include the platform parameter, given that future users of the script or Maven build might be running on different platforms, like Windows or an Intel-based Linux? Will this parameter -- unnecessary for them -- prevent the container from running, or make it run in a slower emulation mode? I'm hoping it's just ignored if not needed.

Comment: I'd worry more about making things unnecessarily inefficient on your Mac M1 when there's a future arm64 version of the container that could run natively instead of through Rosetta. On anything that's already natively amd64 using Linux syscalls it should be a noop.

Comment: Anyhow -- it's easy enough to make an argument conditional if you're inclined to do so. `docker_args=( ); case "$(uname -o -m)" in "amd64 Darwin") docker_args+=( --platform linux/amd64 );; esac; docker run "${docker_args[@]}" ...` for a variety of overkill that makes it easy to add more optional arguments for other specific platforms.

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful. I would like to know if the flag in benign on other platforms though, especially if I need to go the Maven Fabric8 route, which looks probable. Also, you make a good point about a possible native  M1 version of the MS SQL image, but I don't really know how to make a configuration that works now, and also takes advantage of the future upgrade that may or may not happen.